# What do you call a false ceiling dropped below a main ceiling used for indirect lighting?

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I'm wanting to provide some character and define our lounge room space with a large flat ceiling that is hung below the main ceiling.  The edge of which I can install lighting and create a nice effect like below:

[image]

But I'm having trouble with the terminology.  What do you call this? If I google drop ceiling or suspended ceiling what I come up with is pictures of the traditional suspended ceiling you find in office spaces that hide pipework and air conditioning ducts etc.

In addition, in finding out what this is called how would I go about constructing it?  I don't want something too heavy or expensive to construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are referred to as ceiling clouds or [architectural ceiling clouds](https://www.google.com/search?q=architectural%20ceiling%20cloud&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=N8MfU67bEojkrAHsxIGADA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=928).

Comment: That's great, now I'm seeing what I'm looking for.  But not much out there on how to build it apart from buying crazy expensive prebuilt ones.  Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Matt - The one in your picture would be relatively easy to make (looks like it is drywalled and you could just set the connection to ceiling back a foot so that it appears floating).  Any good contractor/carpenter should be able to give you that look.  Most of the prebuilt ones are for office environments and they can get really expensive - these are usually made of metal or a tough plastic.  These can be had for a decent price - but you have to be willing to take their display item or what they couldn't unload.

Comment: Ok I think I might just make up some frames and drywall it.  What is the best way to attach it to the ceiling? Given that it'd best be quite close to an already lowish ceiling (2.4m stud height). Would I make the whole thing first or make a frame and attach that, then put the drywall underneath?

Comment: Matt you frame this out almost exactly how you would a box around a air duct.  You will probably attach this to joists above in multiple places.  The only thing "hard" about this is making the top edge look perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Having been in the business for over twenty years I would say "ceiling clouds" is a relatively new term, although I would instantly know what the customer was referring to if they used this to describe it.

Personally I would refer to it as a "ceiling raft".